Physical interpretation of the square of the Ricci tensor
I know that the Ricci scalar $\mathcal{R}=g^{\mu \nu} R_{\mu \nu}$ intutively measures the local "curvature radius" at each point in a manifold (if the manifold can be approximated by by an osculating sphere around a point, that sphere will have radius proportional to $1/\sqrt{\mathcal{R}})$. If the curvature is negative I assume something equivalent will hold but with the sphere swapped for a hyperbolic space). There are also many answers here that elaborate on the physical interpretation of the Kretschmann scalar $K=R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$, relating it to the strength of tidal forces around a point.
What about the scalar given by $R^2 = R^{\mu \nu}R_{\mu \nu}$? What does the value of this thing say about the manifold? Is there an intuitive or geometric way to understand it?
Aside from the geometric interpretation, I am curious if a nonvanishing $R^2$ would allow one to assign some characteristic scale to a manifold in the case where the Ricci scalar vanishes. An example would be a charged black hole (Reissner-Nordström) in GR. By scale I mean some characteristic length or size, like the "AdS radius" of an AdS spacetime or the usual radius of a sphere, both of which are directly related to the Ricci scalar. Also in the case of GR, if $R=0$ one could use Einstein's equations to trade $R^2$ for $T^2=T^{\mu \nu}T_{\mu \nu}$ and try to understand that instead, but the physical meaning of $T^2$ is also not very clear to me, other than the fact that it should be negligible where the sources are negligible.

Minor comment: Ricci scalar $R$ of a sphere is related to its radius $r$ by $R \sim 1/r^2$, so the scaling you quote is not quite right. I am also skeptical that you can approximate a manifold by a sphere at an arbitrary point, since the curvature need not be isotropic.

@Cham could you elaborate a bit more on why $R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}$ might be negative?

@Noone, in a free fall frame we have $g^{00} = 1$, $g^{0 i} = 0$ and $g^{ij} = - \delta^{ij}$ (locally).  Then, locally: $$R^{ab} R_{ab} \equiv g^{ac} g^{bd} R_{cd} R_{ab} = R_{00}^2 - 2 R_{0 i} R_{0i} + R_{ij} R_{ij},$$The second term is negative and may be dominant in some spacetime (I don't know of any specific example of that case.  All the spacetimes I know do give a positive value for this invariant).
